# creating an empty row to snmp4j MOTable

Tags: java, agent, snmp4j

I have created an snmp agent simulator and implemented conceptual row in it.So i want to add an empty row to the MOTable in snmp4j. I tried the code below.

```
private MOTableRow createEmptyRow(MOTable motable, OID index)
{
    Variable[] vars = new Variable[motable.getColumnCount()];
    // Arrays.fill(vars, new Integer32(1));

    int i = 0;
    for (MOColumn column : motable.getColumns()) {
        switch (column.getSyntax()) {
        case MibConstants.OCTET_STRING: {
            vars[i++] = new OctetString();
            break;
        }
        case MibConstants.INTEGER:
        case MibConstants.INTEGER32: {
            vars[i++] = new Integer32();
            break;
        }
        case MibConstants.COUNTER:
        case MibConstants.COUNTER32: {
            vars[i++] = new Counter32();
            break;
        }
        case MibConstants.COUNTER64: {
            vars[i++] = new Counter64();
            break;
        }
        case MibConstants.IPADDRESS: {
            vars[i++] = new IpAddress();
            break;
        }
        case MibConstants.DISPLAYSTRING: {
            vars[i++] = new OctetString();
            break;
        }
        case MibConstants.GAUGE:
        case MibConstants.GAUGE32: {
            vars[i++] = new Gauge32();
            break;
        }
        case MibConstants.OID: {
            vars[i++] = new OID();

            break;
        }
        case MibConstants.ROW_STATUS: {
            vars[i++] = new Integer32(RowStatus.active);

            break;
        }
        default: {
            vars[i++] = new OctetString();
            break;
        }
        }

    }

    MOTableRow row = DefaultMOFactory.getInstance().createRow(index, vars);

    return row;
}
```

But it some times generates an "Snmp general error" and sometimes a "Bad value"! What exactly wrong here? How can i create an empty row if it's not working? Please help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `SMIConstants` instead of `MIBConstants`.
`SMIConstants` is a class in `SNMP4j` library. But `SMIConstants` does not include `ROW_STATUS`.